# Creating an array of objects 9

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to create a deck of cards. The deck should be an array and each of the cards should be an object

```
Card(int value, String name, int suit)
```

The int value is the rank of the card: Two = 2, Three = 3, . . ., Jack = 11

The String name is "Two", "Three, . ., "Ace".

The int suit can be: 0, 1, 2 or 3. Where 0 = Clubs, 1 = Diamonds, 2 = Hearts, 3 = Spades

I know how to create the Card object. The problem I'm having is when I should create the Card[] deck array.
Obviously I could do it one at a time:

```
Card[] deck = new Card[52];
deck[0] = new Card(2, "Two", 0); // Two of clubs, value = 2
deck[1] = new Card(3, "Three", 0); // Three of clubs, value = 3
```

But it would be good to do it with loops. But I can't get it right..

Comment: Could you show us your failed attempt? That way we can point out mistakes instead of providing you with a new solution.

Comment: What did you try with loops? Isn't it working?

Comment: See [The `for` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials. If you need more specific help, ask a more specific question instead of just saying "I can't get it right". What did you try and why did it fail?

Comment: Try a nested loop! Also your suits can be like `Suit.SPADES` and so on where `Suit` is an enum

Comment: There is no "One of clubs"...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an array first to map the value of the card with its name.

E.g.

```
String[] cardNames = new String[] {"", "", "Two", "Three", ...};
```

Then you can use a nested loop.

```
Card[] deck = new Card[52];
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for(int j = 2; j < 15; j++) {
    deck[count] = new Card(j, cardNames[j], i);
  }
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(the loops can be made better but wanted to give you an idea),

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class CardExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Card[] deck = new Card[52];
        Map<Integer, String> cardSeq = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        cardSeq.put(1, "Ace");
        cardSeq.put(2, "Two");
        cardSeq.put(3, "Three");
        cardSeq.put(4, "Four");
        cardSeq.put(5, "Five");
        cardSeq.put(6, "Six");
        cardSeq.put(7, "Seven");
        cardSeq.put(8, "Eight");
        cardSeq.put(9, "Nine");
        cardSeq.put(10, "Ten");
        cardSeq.put(11, "Jack");
        cardSeq.put(12, "Queen");
        cardSeq.put(13, "King");

        int counter=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> it = cardSeq.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<Integer, String> pair = it.next();
                deck[counter]=new Card(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue(), i);
                counter++;
            }

        }

        for(Card c:deck){
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}

class Card {
    private int value;
    private String name;
    private int suit;

    Card(int value, String name, int suit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Card [value=" + value + ", name=" + name + ", suit=" + suit + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: are u still searching for the answers?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is actually no need for you to explicitly store the name of the rank(Ace, Two, Three...), you can just create a method that return the name of the rank based on the rank value. I would redesign your `Card` class to be something like this.

```
class Card {
    private int suit, rank;

    Card(int suit, int rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getRankName() {
        switch(rank)
        {
        case 11:
            return "J";
        case 12:
            return "Q";
        case 13:
            return "K";
        case 14:
            return "A";
        default:
            return Integer.toString(rank);
        }
    }

    //other getters, setters, methods....
}
```

Next simply use a nested for loop to create the `Card` objects

```
Card[] deck = new Card[52];
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  for(int j = 2; j < 15; ++j) {
    deck[index] = new Card(i, j);
  }
  ++index;
}
```